VLOOKUP but instead of matching data, just mark X?
I have data in sheet 1 and sheet 2.
I'm trying to use a MATCH/INDEX/VLOOKUP formula, to find data in another column.
HOWEVER - instead of retuning the value or matching - I Just want to mark an X (or check mark etc).
Sheet 1 will be a simplified version that is printable for my fieldtechs.
Any help is appreciated!
All attempts only providing matches.
Working with Excel 2013 so possibly limited (VBA available).

IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP()), "", "x")

Either way, you are matching so it's a job for the MATCH function. In e.g. cell B2 of Sheet1 use =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A$2:A$11,0)),"X","") and copy down.

Try:
IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP()), "", "x")

